# Custom Raster/Vector Maps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, maps, raster

I would like to access custom raster/vector maps on iPhone for an iPhone application, I am building. Is there a way to have the maps offline on iPhone? Also how to track the path along with GPS location? Is there a framework available?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041676/how-can-use-openlayers-in-iphone-sdk/42988812#42988812).

Answer (score 2):

there's several options to get maps offline.

Look for free solutions from CloudMade - http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/iphone-sdk - it's **not** oflline by default, but, it has ability to cache map tiles and you can control that process, and pre-cache required regions.

Also - there's opensource project called RouteMe https://github.com/route-me/route-me - CloudMade's maps are based on it, and you can use RouteMe sources to go in deep customisation.

Other options are proprietary APIs, you can try to use:

- iosphere - http://www.iosphere.de/quartzmaps.shtml
- MapBox - http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/ - *by the way, foursquare are using them*