# how can use openlayers in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openlayers

I want to create a customize map using by openlayer.But I am unable to use openlayer. I want to create map without using google map in iphone so I want to use other way in which I can fill own data in map. i think it possible by open layer , but how I dont know.So please help me.

Comment: You will get a better response if you state the code you've tried to use with OpenLayers and why it hasn't worked.  Also try an [OpenLayers tutorial](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/ol.html).

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers is a javascript library. As a client-based map viewing utility it allows to ["display map tiles, vector data and markers loaded from any source"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers). It is similar to [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).

Both of them are only helpful if you want to render on the web (in which case you would need to grab map tiles or a map image from somewhere ([OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) for instance), or set up your own map server).

If what you want is to render a map natively on iOS, then you'll probably need a toolkit to fetch and render the map tiles or image. Here're a few that could be helpful:

- [WhirlyGlobe-Maply](https://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/);
- [tangram-es](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es);
- [GLMap](https://getyourmap.com/get_started/#objc);
- [Mapzen iOS SDK](https://github.com/mapzen/ios);
- [Nutiteq SDK](https://www.nutiteq.com/nutiteq-sdk/overview/);
- [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/)
- [QuartzMaps](https://iosphere.de/en/products/quartzmaps/);

Comment: @famfamfam From what I'm aware, only [WhirlyGlobe-Maply](https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe) and [Tangram ES](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es) are FOSS. All other are open-source but not necessarily free.

Comment: As far as I know, you can consume any tile service with Tangram, from OpenStreetMap to GeoJSON/TopoJSON vector data. It will be paid only if you choose a paid service. Also, just because you need an api key it doesn't mean it's paid. :-) Example: [Netzen](https://www.nextzen.org/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this by help of [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).

if you dont want to use phonegap then you can simply use UIWebView for that.you can load your data in it.
load HTML files in UIWebView. html file including javascript and css and image files without any problem.

```
NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:path];
 [yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath]]];
```

for more info on [openLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/)